# met vs have met

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

I have a question about simple past and present perfect. This sentence:

> Her husband is a very nice man. I have liked him ever since I met him.

Why do we use "met" and we don't use "have met"? I think we should use "have met" because the action is still in progress, is not over. It's wrong?

Comment: I think it's because the action of ***meeting*** isn't "still in progress" (plus you can only really ***meet*** at one moment in time; there's no "duration"). You could use Present Perfect after ***ever since*** if the action referenced is progressive, AND *if it continues right up until time of utterance*. For example: *I have liked him ever since I **have known** him*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, the structure is basically this:

> I have liked him since <some occurrence/point in time>.

The occurrence was simply that you met him.

One way to understand this would be to add a few words that would not make sense if you used "have":

> I have liked him ever since **the moment/time** I met him.

Also, the action still in progress is the liking him (where you have correctly included "have"), and not the meeting him.